# SQLite query, subquery and performance improvement

Tags: performance, sqlite

In SQLite is there any other way to write this statement:

```
SELECT tape_id,title 
FROM tapes 
WHERE tape_id NOT IN (SELECT tape_id 
                      FROM tapeGenres)
```

and improve performances?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT tapes.tape_id, tapes.title
FROM tapes
LEFT JOIN tapeGenres ON tapes.tape_id = tapeGenres.tape_id;
WHERE tapeGenres.tape_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option might be to use [NOT EXISTS](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) but the biggest performance improvement would be gained by using appropriate indexes.

If not already present, you might try adding

- an index on `tapeGenres.tape_id`
- a covering index on `tapes (tape_id, title)`

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT tapes.tape_id, tapes.title
FROM   tapes t
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT tape_id FROM tapeGenres WHERE tape_id = t.tape_id)
```